# Need the average of last 17 days and compare with previous 17 days

Tags: teradata

I was looking for a query which will provide me the count to records loaded for the last 17 days and compare the count with next 17 days.

There is a drop in the records loaded and i have to see the drop and also check the percentage drop if possible. I was checking the moving average window function but there is an option of number of rows and not days.

```
sel call_start_dt,count(*) from dpd.network_activity where call_start_dt > date-45 and dtype_cd='8,006'
 group by call_start_dt
 order by call_start_dt desc
```

This is my base query.

Required Output:

```
call_start_dt  count(*) average( for last 17 days)
1st june        1000     800
2nd june         675     800
....
....
17 rows
call_strat_dt count(*) average( next 17 days)
next 17 rows
```

Comment: You want a *moving average* based on the current row's data +/- 17days? If you got data for each day you can simply use `rows between 17 preceding and 1 preceding` (same for `following`). Otherwise it's a bit more complicated and you need to EXPAND ON first.

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth,
Checking on that.